# Use an existing database with Redbean

Tags: php, redbean

I can't find much about using RedBean with an existing database, other than a Google Groups posting saying you can but it has to match 100%.

I need documentation or information on mapping an existing database for use with Redbean, i.e. I don't want Redbean to create the schema itself, but use the existing database.

Does anyone have experience in doing this?

Comment: What *specific* problem did you run into with RedBean? Comparing RedBean and Doctrine is like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Yes I know; I haven't tried doing it in RedBean yet as I want to use an existing database.

Comment: So you haven't tried, yet somehow you are stuck? I know that RB expects certain conventions, but since you have not provided a specific problem there's not much I can help you with other than to say look at `R::setStrictTyping(false);`. You haven't even provided your schema details.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063640/redbean-vs-doctrine

Comment: I thought this question was fairly clear but there seems to be some ambiguity. I have edited it accordingly. I am after information on mapping an existing database in Redbean, there doesn't seem to be information on the Redbean site to do this.

Comment: I think you spoke too soon because I don't see any edits. I thought my questions were pretty clear TBH.

Answer (score 2):

Use doctrine if your schema does not follow the redbean conventions

i.e. something like this:

- object type = table name, lowercase
- a column named _id is considered a back reference
- a table named _ is a many-to-many mapping between type a and type b
- primary key as ID of integer type.